# How to use a promisified function tha returns a bool as an if condition?

Tags: javascript, promise

Is this the right way to use a function that returns a promise which resolves with either true or false inside an if condition?

```
if(functionName().then(function(data){return data})){
    //execute code
}
```

Comment: It's not the right way since it will return a promise which is always truthy, and the if will always execute the code.

Comment: @evolutionxbox But I am also attaching a .then call inside, will that not return the data the function's promise resolved with?

Comment: You're supposed to have the `if` block inside the `then` callback

Comment: `data` will not be accessible outside the `then`

Comment: Can you please share a snippet on how to have a function as an if condition which returns a promise that resolves(always) with either a true or a false?

Comment: If you want to run some code when the result of the promise you can use:
`functionName().then(function (data){ if (data){ /*execute code*/ }}`
or
`if(await functionName())` (check browser support)